# How to programmatically save a value in a long text with summary field?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type which has a field of type "long text with summary".

When I to try programmatically save a node with the code below, the value is not being saved.

How can I save the data into the field and set the format to "full_html"?

what does not work (assume the rest of the fields are set):

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type ='some_type';
$node->language = 'en';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->field_custom_description_value = 'some_value';
$node->field_custom_description_format = 'full_html';

/* I also tried this */
$node->field_custom_description[$node->language][0]['value']-> 'some_value';
$node->field_custom_description[$node->language][0][format]-> 'full_html';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget the `#` in the `#format`, use this:

```
$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#format'] = 'full_html';
$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#format'] = 'filtered_html';
```

Read this: [How to set the default format per content type at Drupal 7?](http://drupal.org/node/1003262#comment-6164084)

Comment: Thank you Adrian! I was using "en" instead of "LANGUAGE_NONE". once i used LANGUAGE_NONE, it resolved the issue.

To prove this i also used the Devel module to check the results and it verified everything you recommended. 

https://www.drupal.org/project/devel

Comment: @sf_admin819 a pleasure and god luck in your projects.